# Arrange list string data in ascending order

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I have following data :

```
{
  20*20,
  20*10,
  30*20,
  30*10,
  10*14,
  10*20,
  10*15
}
```

I have copied this data in List to access further in app but i want to arrange this list in ascending order like below :

```
{
   10*14,
   10*15,
   10*20,
   20*10,
   20*20,
   30*10,
   30*20,
}
```

I have tried sort method some how i am not able to get the expected result.

How can i do that ?

Comment: convert String array to integer array first, then use short method of java.

Answer (score 1):

Your example data does indeed sort as text alphabetically. **No need to do anything** but wrap enclosing quote marks needed for string literals.

```java
List <String > list =
    new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(
              "20*20",
              "20*10",
              "30*20",
              "30*10",
              "10*14",
              "10*20",
              "10*15"
        )
    )
;
Collections.sort( list ) ;
System.out.println( list ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/m7t4xT).

```
[10*14, 10*15, 10*20, 20*10, 20*20, 30*10, 30*20]
```